# Palette windows/floating tool windows (C# .NET)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, floating, palette

My app needs floating palette windows. I've already implemented this behavior on my own and it worked great for when it was a single document app, but now my app requires multiple document windows. My attempts to adapt the palette windowing system for this now makes the implementation too hacky and doesn't work very well when switching documents.

Windows has an extended window style, `WS_EX_PALETTEWINDOW`, which I have tried using through overriding `CreateParams` but this keeps my floating windows on top of EVERY other running app. I need them to just stay on top of my app and go away when another app is enters the foreground.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Preferrably solutions should not involve the use of MDI containers as I need document windows to be top level windows in their own right.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DockPanel suite](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/). It is a ready made library for handling tool windows.

In addition you can enable user customizable docking of the tool windows if you like.

Comment: I will check this out when I get back to work, it looks good, but I'm not sure how it will perform with multiple document windows not inside an MDI container.